# Does onclick default to ontouch

Tags: javascript, html, touch, event-listener

If I have a webpage and I want to monitor clicks and touches on a `div`, do I have to add event listeners for each event or will a `touch` event act as a `click` event by default on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default `touch`ing an element on a mobile device will fire its `click` event handler. However, this behavior is usually undesirable since it allows for a 300ms delay before the event handler function runs. See [this blog post](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

use this `mousedown()`

But this will record even drag and all kinda mouse button clicks.

```
$('yourelementid').mousedown(function(e){
if( (e.which == 1) ) {
     alert("left button");
   }if( (e.which == 3) ) {
     alert("right button");
   }else if( (e.which == 2) ) {
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

try this...

Answer (score 0):

Try giving both events side by side

```
$('myDiv').on("mousedown touchstart", function (e) {
    if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
 //try mousemove touchmove together
 // define your logic

})
```